# Including a css file in a React project

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to use material UI with react.

On this website: https://jamesmfriedman.github.io/rmwc/installation

It says

material-components-web should be installed automatically as a peer dependency. Include node_modules/material-components-web/dist/material-components-web.min.css in your project via your method of choice (using a link tag, a css-loader, etc.).

But I am not sure what this actually means. How and where do I have to import that file to use this library?

Answer (score 1):

At first, you should add the library to your project by running:

`npm install --save rmwc` or `yarn add rmwc`

Secondly, you should understand the following:

Generally speaking, [**Material Components Web**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web) library is actually *a bunch of prebuilt design styles* that you can link to your project to make it look *Material*.

The library that you are using, [**React Material Web Components [RMWC]**](https://jamesmfriedman.github.io/rmwc/), is a React wrapper for the previous library. It means that it gives you *a set of flexible React Components* like `<Button />`, `<TextField />`, etc that are built in React and act in a virtual DOM.

It doesn't give any specific styling to the elements. Moreover, it is designed not to provide you any extra styling. To make your imported React components look *Material*, you should add the styling from the parent library [Material Components Web].

To add styling from that library, use the following:

Add it to your project:

`npm install material-components-web` or `yarn add material-components-web`

And then use the following line (use it once in your project):

`import 'node_modules/material-components-web/dist/material-components-web.min.css';`

Comment: Thanks. I am actually trying to customize the styles for my react app. But how do we actually do it? What do I need to do after adding the line `import 'node_modules/material-components-web/dist/material-components-web.min.css';`?

Comment: After you successfully add the minified css file to your project, you should get a bunch of CSS classes that you can override in your code. That's the easiest way to achieve that. 
The second way (more complicated but more flexible) is to add **sass** files from the `material-components-web` library to your project. Then you should configure your Webpack loader to handle **sass** files and use **sass** mixins like `@import "@material/button/mdc-button"`. There's a nice instruction in the official docs: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web#include-css-for-a-component

Comment: I followed this Google codelab: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mdc-112-web/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0

However, the tutorial shows nothing about changing the style of the component. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Dawn17, if you want to override the styling, e.g.  `<section className='mdc-top-app-bar__section> .... </section>`, create your own `styles.css` file, then write down you styles `.mdc-top-app-bar__section { ... <your styles> ... }` and import your `styles.css` file to your code .. Sounds good ?

Comment: where can we see all those class names that we can override? Also, how do we set the color codes for the primary and secondary theme? The `RMWC` seems to have it, but I am not sure how to do it with the `Material Component Web`. I would like to apply the theme to all components that I use. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

RMWC does the ReactJS wrapping. The styling is still all done by MDC.

You can add the minified mdc css file to your project, but that will not give you much customization. I'd advise using sass for your project and importing that mdc modules there. This way you can change variables e.g. from primary color as explained here: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/tree/master/packages/mdc-theme

```
$mdc-theme-primary: #fcb8ab;
$mdc-theme-secondary: #feeae6;
$mdc-theme-on-primary: #442b2d;
$mdc-theme-on-secondary: #442b2d;

@import "@material/button/mdc-button";
```

A more in depth documentation on how to use styling specifically with RMWC can be found in the docu: https://jamesmfriedman.github.io/rmwc/styling

But overall you can either create your own classes you then apply to your elements such as buttons. E.g.

```
.my-button-style {
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Or you override the mdc classes directly.
    .mdc-button {
      border-radius: 10px;
    }

The mdc classes can be found in each of the package sites on GitHub. (e.g. for button: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/tree/master/packages/mdc-button)